# Django DRF with django-tenants Unit Test Issue

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-tenants

**Description**:

I am working on a Django project using Django Rest Framework (DRF) and django-tenants for multi-tenancy. In my unit tests, I'm encountering an error that I need help resolving.

**Issue**:

When running a unit test to create a restaurant using the TenantTestCase, I am getting the following error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_create_valid_restaurant (django_apis.restaurants.tests.RestaurantCreateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OK\BackendProjects\apis\django_apis\restaurants\tests.py", line 55, in test_create_valid_restaurant
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 404 != 201

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 4.596s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**Code**:

Here's the relevant code for the unit test:

```
class RestaurantCreateTest(TenantTestCase):
    tenant = None  # Define a class attribute to store the tenant instance

    @classmethod
    def setup_tenant(cls, tenant):
        tenant.name = "kangaroo"
        tenant.subdomain_prefix = "kangaroo"

        # Store the tenant instance as a class attribute
        cls.tenant = tenant

        return tenant

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.c = TenantClient(self.tenant)

    # Override the get_test_tenant_domain method to specify a custom test domain
    @staticmethod
    def get_test_tenant_domain():
        if RestaurantCreateTest.tenant:
            domain = f"{RestaurantCreateTest.tenant.subdomain_prefix + settings.ORGANIZATION_DOMAIN}"
            return domain
        else:
            return "tenant.test.com"  # Default custom test domain if tenant is not set

    def test_create_valid_restaurant(self):
        url = reverse("Restaurant-list")
        # url = "http://localhost:8000/restaurants/"
        data = {
            "name": "Sample Restaurant",
            "address": "123 Main Street",
            "phone_number": "555-123-4567",
            "email": "sample@example.com",
            "cuisine": "Italian",
            "rating": 4.5,
        }
        response = self.c.post(url, data, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        # Check if the restaurant object was created in the database
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(name="Sample Restaurant")
        self.assertIsNotNone(restaurant)

        # Check if the response data matches the serialized restaurant
        serializer = RestaurantSerializer(restaurant)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
```

**Additional Information:**

I'm using django-tenants for multi-tenancy.
The error suggests a 404 status code instead of the expected 201 Created status when creating a restaurant.
I've verified my URL configuration, view names, and tenant setup, but the issue persists.

**Request**:

I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully create a restaurant in my unit test using django-tenants with DRF. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: when I worked on DRF project, too faced the issue, solved using URLPatternsTestCase the https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#urlpatternstestcase

Comment: path('api/', include('api.urls')),  # some thing same defined in your urls.py,  this is how I fixed the 404 issue.

Comment: @Jisson care to share snippet of the code? I have added the URLPatternsTestCase as per link you shared and I still get the error, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't have the exact code I tried, hope the flowing link may help you, https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-good-way-to-write-the-test-cases-for-rest-API/answer/Jisson-Varghese

Comment: Maybe because I am using django-tenants, that's why I am not getting the same results as you. BTW, My tests were running fine before using django-tenants